# How to show child element outside of parent on x axis and have y axis scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show elements outside of parent dimensions on the x axis while allowing the parent element to scroll on the y axis.

Foolish me, I thought "I'll just set the parent to overflow-x:visible and overflow-y:auto". Of course, it doesn't work as I intended, instead it makes the x axis scrollable thereby hiding the child element behind a scroll.

Example html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  width: 50px;
  background: black;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: -85px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  background: purple;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xphc0qyo/

This seems to be a known issue but I'm unaware of a good and easy solution or is the best option to go the Javascript route?

So, how to show child elements outside of a parent on the x axis and have the y axis scrollable?